# Is there an alternative formula for Substitute in ms excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please can you suggest a formula alternative to substitute? Currently I'm using below formula to extract the keyword. This formula extract the string just before the ":Start" word:-

*Content:* Problem-Myproblems-Problems-**HerProblems:Start**-Yourproblems

*Result:* **HerProblems**

***FORMULA:-***

```
=IF(LEN(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("Start",A1)-2))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("Start",A1)-2),"-",""))<>0,MID(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("Start",A1)-2),FIND(CHAR(7),SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("Start",A1)-2),"-",CHAR(7),LEN(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("Start",A1)-2))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("Start",A1)-2),"-",""))))+1,50),LEFT(A1,SEARCH("Start",A1)-2))
```

1. This formula removes the string after the ":Start" firstly.
2. Then count the "-" using substitute
3. Then again use the same substitute formula to mark the last "-" next to the keyword ":Start" with a different symbol using `Char(7)`
4. Find the location of `Char(7)`
5. Used `MID` function to cut the string between Symbol `Char(7)` and Start

I've written this formula yesterday, but the use of substitute formula multiple times are not efficient and was looking for an alternative, please advice if there are any.

thanks
Anish

***Few more examples:***

*Example2:*
Problem-Myproblems-**checkproblems:Start**-Problems-Yourproblems

Result: **checkproblems**

*Example3:* Problem-Myproblems-Problems-Yourproblems-**Sillyproblems:Start**

Result: **Sillyproblems**

Comment: Can you give more than 1 example of your strings please

Comment: Example2:
Problem-Myproblems-**checkproblems:Start**-Problems-Yourproblems
Result: _checkproblems_

Example3:
Problem-Myproblems-Problems-Yourproblems-**Sillyproblems:Start**
Result: _Sillyproblems_

Comment: (Can you edit that in to your original post, instead of comments? It's hard to understand the format when in comments).

Comment: Thank you; I've just edited the question to include few more example

Comment: @anish.rossvilla Can you please check below answer and feedback?

Comment: thanks, worked perfectly for me.

Comment: @anish.rossvilla Glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following formula

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("Start",A1)-2),"-", REPT(" ",100)),100))
```

***Screenshot***
[image]

Comment: The only thing I notice is that you could search for ":Start" to make it a little more foolproof.

Comment: @DougGlancy That's a good idea but still you need to minus 1 from `Search()` function result which I am doing minus 2.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I just meant in case one of the string started with "Start". Good answer though.

Comment: @DougGlancy That's tricky. Thanks to catch it. If there is any other word with start then my formula will give wrong answer. So it is better to implement your idea `:Start`.

Comment: Something like: `=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",REPT(" ",99)),FIND(":Start",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",REPT(" ",99)),1)-99,99))`

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of any trailing characters with REPLACE then use SUBSTITUTE to widen any hyphen to a large number of spaces. TRIM a RIGHT substring.

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(A2, FIND(":Start", A2)+LEN(":Start"), LEN(A2), ""), "-", REPT(" ", LEN(A2))), LEN(A2)))
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvzs9.png)